# TableView will not update after adding new row to array [[self tableView] reloadData] doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios6

I've working on a program and I'm having issues getting a tableView to update.  Pretty much I have an tableView and there is nothing but empty rows at first.  Then the user hits the + sign and I PUSH a new tableview on top of the stack and the user can select from a master list of which rows they want to add to the initial table.  The rows that the user picks are added to an array.  When the user clicks the back button, the first table doesn't update.  However, if I press the HOME key and then reload the app, the first table view displays the updated array.  I have included the code from both tables and my gloabl array.

.m File for first table

```
@interface baseTableViewViewController ()

@end

@implementation baseTableViewViewController

//@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self; }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     }

-(void)viewDidlAppear:(BOOL)animated{



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. }


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[[DataClass getInstance]allItems]count]; }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"base"];

    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"base"];
    }

    BaseInfo *infoAtIndex = [[[DataClass getInstance] allItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[infoAtIndex name]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[infoAtIndex icao]];
    return cell; }

-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib]; }

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [[self tableView]reloadData];
     }

@end

.h file for first table



@class baseTableViewViewController; @class BaseInfoDataController;

@interface baseTableViewViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;


@end
```

.m file for second table (the master list)

```
@class BaseInfo; @interface MasterListTableViewController ()


@end

@implementation MasterListTableViewController @synthesize delegate;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self; }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];   }


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. }



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.dataController countOfList]; }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Base";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    BaseInfo *infoAtIndex = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:infoAtIndex.name];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:infoAtIndex.icao];

    return cell; }




- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSMutableArray *addBaseList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.masterList = addBaseList;
    BaseInfo *inform;


    if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone){
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

        inform = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%@",inform.name);
        NSLog(@"%@",inform.icao);

        [DataClass.getInstance addObject:inform];




    }else{
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
     }

-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.dataController = [[MasterListDataController alloc]init]; }

-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender{

    [self masterListTableViewControllerDidCancel:self];

}

-(IBAction)done:(id)sender{

    [self masterListTableViewControllerDidSave:self]; }


-(void)masterListTableViewControllerDidCancel:(MasterListTableViewController
*)controller{

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; }



-(void)masterListTableViewControllerDidSave:(MasterListTableViewController
*)controller{

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; }


@end
```

below is the .h for the second table

```
@class MasterListTableViewController; @class BaseInfo;




@interface MasterListTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate; @property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *masterList; @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray
*baseNames; @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *icao; @property (strong, nonatomic) MasterListDataController *dataController; @property (nonatomic, copy)BaseInfo *inform;


- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

-(void)masterListTableViewControllerDidCancel:(MasterListTableViewController
*)controller;
-(void)masterListTableViewControllerDidsave:(MasterListTableViewController
*)controller;

@end
```

and finally the global array that i'm using with the methods

```
@implementation DataClass @synthesize userBaseList;

+(DataClass *)getInstance{
    static DataClass *instance = nil;
    //@synchronized(self)
    {
        //if(instance ==nil)
        if(!instance)
        {
            //instance = [DataClass new];
            instance = [[super allocWithZone:nil]init];
        }
    }
    return instance; }

-(void)addObject:(BaseInfo*)info{
    [self.userBaseList addObject:info];
     }
-(void)removeObjectAtIndex:(NSInteger)atIndex{
    [self.userBaseList removeObjectAtIndex:atIndex]; }

+(id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    return [self getInstance]; }
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        userBaseList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return self; }
-(NSArray *)allItems{
    return userBaseList; } @end
```

I think the solution has to be something very simple that I'm missing, but I just don't see it.  I've read through the apple developers guide for uitableview development, but I'm still stuck.

Comment: In the DidSelectedRowAtIndexPath method of "MasterListTableViewController", you will add object in DataClass to reflect in "baseTableViewViewController", Am i correct? Can you please post the code?

Comment: posted.  I thought I did it the first time.  It's under the second table .m coding post.  Yea, that is correct, but when I go back to the first table, the rows aren't updated.  However, if I press the home button and then reopen the app up, the array gets loaded and the new rows are there.

Comment: I just figured it out.  I had to define table 1 as a UITableViewController instead of a UIViewController.  I don't know why this didn't let my table update, but it's working now!

Comment: could you please format your code as code and not as quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed table 1.h to the following:

```
@class baseTableViewViewController; @class BaseInfoDataController;

@interface baseTableViewViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;


@end
```

I had to define it as a UITableViewController instead of a UIViewController.  Once I corrected this, it refreshed the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating an instance of DataClass's super class and not DataClass.  You don't need to define allocWithZone, and it is wrong anyway.  You just need this:

```
-(id)init { 
    self = [super init];
    if (self) { 
        userBaseList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}
+(DataClass *)getInstance {
    static DataClass *instance = nil;
    if(!instance)
        instance = [[DataClass alloc]init];
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help.  Changed my code, but I'm still getting the same issue